# When to use " is same as" and when to use "=="

Tags: templating, difference

```
{% if foo is same as('bar') %}
```

vs.

```
{% if foo == 'bar' %}
```

When to use first and when to use second? Does one of them has advantages over another?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the Twig code, they have this documented for the “same as” test:

> Checks if a variable is the same as another one (=== in PHP).

I won’t re-hash the details of === vs. == in PHP because there is an excellent comparison here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp

The money quote is:

> == compares the values of variables for equality, type casting as necessary. === checks if the two variables are of the same type AND have the same value.

And here’s what the PHP docs have to say:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

For example:

`false == 0` will be `true`

`false === 0` will be `false`

It is very useful when you use such functions as `file_put_contents()` and `preg_match()`.

The first function returns a number of bytes writtent to the file (which can be 0 if nothing was written what does not mean that it's false). And the second one returns 1 if something was found otherwise 0.

They always warn people when you must check for the variable type too. [Php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php): Go at "Return values" and you will see a red Warning block.