# How can I determine if a user is logged in, and who that user is?

Tags: templating, users, current-user

I'm running some checks to see if there is a user logged in, and if that user is someone specific. When accessing `user.isCurrent` it's returning `1` when I'm logged in, but returns `null` when I'm not. Should this be returning `0` or false in that case, or should I be checking `{% if user.isCurrent is defined %}` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To determine if the user is logged in at all, you'll want to use the [currentUser](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables#currentUser) variable:

```
{% if currentUser %}
    Welcome, {{ currentUser.friendlyName }}!
{% endif %}
```

To determine if the logged in user is a *specific* user, then simply compare against their username:

```
{% if currentUser and currentUser.username is 'johndoe' %}
    Hey Johnny Boy!
{% endif %}
```

The [isCurrent](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#isCurrent) method is useful when targeting a more generic [UserModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel) (where you don't know if the user would be the current user).

```
{% for user in craft.users %}
    {% if user.isCurrent %}
        {{ user.friendlyName }} is you!
    {% else %}
        {{ user.friendlyName }} is someone else.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works great thanks for clarifying. I did have an issue with using `is` in this context though: `Unexpected token "string" of value "bill" ("name" expected)` I swapped is with `==` and it seems to working fine now. Maybe some kind of typecast comparison issue?

Comment: Huh, interesting... I wonder if it's just a grouping issue. Perhaps put parenthesis around the second part and try it as `if currentUser and (currentUser.username is 'johndoe')`. In theory, `is` should be parsed exactly the same as `==`. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#test-operator

Comment: Here's another question addressing the topic of `is` vs `is same as` vs `==` vs `===` ... http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/218/when-to-use-is-same-as-and-when-to-use

Comment: @BillColumbia I just bumped into that same issue on a site I'm working on (`is` vs `==`), so I did a little more digging. It looks like `is` represents a "[test operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#test-operator)"... meaning, it runs **[tests](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/index.html)**. Meanwhile, `==` is a "[comparison operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons)". So, I learned something new today... `is` does not directly translate to `==`