# What's the difference between "is defined" and "is not null"?

Tags: templating, null, defined

```
{% if var is defined %}
```

and

```
{% if var is not null %}
```

Is there a difference in usage of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`is defined` - The variable has been defined, and set to any value (or `null`).

`is not null` - The variable has been defined, and is specifically **not** `null`.

In PHP terms, it's like the difference between `is_null()` vs. checking whether the variable exists using `get_defined_vars()` (see this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803282/check-if-value-isset-and-null) for a little more clarity)

---

Try this experiment... Without setting `myVar`, put this in your template:

```
{{ (myVar is defined) }}
```

Since that equates to `false`, nothing will appear in your template. Now change it to this:

```
{{ (myVar is not null) }}
```

That will actually throw an error, since `myVar` was never defined.

Comment: Now I understand ))

Comment: You're a machine, Lindsey.

Comment: Apparently there's some merit to this "gamification" concept. ;)

Comment: Technically `is null` is a test, too. Anything starting with “is” or “is not” is a [test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/index.html). `is null` is just testing for a null value, whereas `is defined` is testing for whether the value exists at all.

Comment: Very good point @BrandonKelly, [I actually learned that](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/351/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-is-logged-in-and-who-that-user-is/352?noredirect=1#comment603_352) a few hours after I posted this answer. I'll go ahead and update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The first statement checks for the existence of `var`, the second checks that it has a value other than `null` and will throw and error if `var` does not exist.

If you're not sure whether a variable exists, you should check if it exists first then check for its value to be safe.

You could combine both statements like so `{% if var is defined and var is not null %}` or use `empty, not empty` if you're feeling fancy: )

Comment: Hey dude, sorry for simultaneously posting! I should probably ease up a bit and give others a chance to answer a few questions. :)

Comment: No worries bro,  you answer is much better: ) Keep up the good work!

Comment: @LindseyD I agree! Give others (me) a chance. In fact, please start emailing me answers.