# How to use a global variable in a conditional statement if an entries relation field is empty?

Tags: templating, conditional, field, entries-field

```
{% if entry.fieldHandle %}
  {{ entry.fieldHandle}}
{% else %}
  {{ global.fieldHandle}}
{% endif %}
```

Doesn't seem to be rendering for me. The entry field shows up when it's true, but the global field doesn't in the cases it needs to.

Comment: Your original code should work, as evaluating an empty array should return false. What type of field is the fieldHandle?

Comment: @BenCroker it was an Entries field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it wasn't rendering is because my original entry field is an *Entries Field* (see [templating examples](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields#examples) in the docs). The relationship fieldtypes (Entries, Assets, Users) require that you include the `length` filter in your conditional like so:

```
{% if entry.fieldHandle |length  %}
  {{ entry.fieldHandle}}
{% else %}
  {{ global.fieldHandle}}
{% endif %}
```

Thanks to Keith Mancuso @keithmancuso for [the fix](https://gist.github.com/keithmancuso/cc2e933491bb9d7afcc3)!

Comment: I added further insight on why you need to include `length` in your conditional. Hope you didn't mind?! :)

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Don't mind at all! Thanks for making it more thorough!

Comment: `{{ entry.fieldHandle|length ? entry.fieldHandle : global.fieldHandle }}` ... Same code written as a simple [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).

Answer (score 2):

For a relationship field you should use the [length filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html):

```
{% if entry.fieldHandle|length  %}
```

Or the more efficient [total function](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#outputting-elements) to get and check against the total number of elements that match the criteria:

```
{% if entry.fieldHandle.total  %}
```

A more detailed answer on how to test for empty fieldtypes is here:
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/842/9

*Note: this answer was edited based on clarification of the question as well as the comments below*

Comment: Hey Ben, at one point I thought the entry variable alone {% if entry.fieldHandle %} was the same as {% if entry.fieldHandle is not empty %} but that doesn't seem to be the case in the way it behaves.  Do you know what the default behavior of {% if entry.fieldHandle %} equates to in Twig?

Comment: i thought i had a grasp on the difference but after reviewing the docs and testing some things i am now unable to find any. i've left a comment for the original question to try to get to the bottom of why the code did not work.

Comment: @BenCroker I think a question to investigate the difference between `{% if entry.fieldHandle %}` and `{% if entry.fieldHandle is not empty %}` would be pretty stellar. I'd post it, but then I'd feel vaguely guilty since you Bens brought it up.

Comment: i think that would be classified as a twig question rather than craft, and frankly i don't think there is a difference in functionality, maybe use case though.

Comment: `{% if entry.fieldHandle %}` is Craft specific and depends on the type of field. See Brandon's [comment on g+](https://plus.google.com/104136663060549664653/posts/VeAQ4QujT6Q).

Comment: @BenCroker Here’s a full breakdown of how to test for whether each field type is empty: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/842/9

Comment: thanks guys! brandon, are you still considering adding the hasValue function to fieldtypes?