# Image asset not being displayed

Tags: templating, assets, field, image, singles

This is my second website I am building with craft cms and I have no prior experience with Twig.

I have had a particular issue with echoing image assets from a singles entry.

The line I copied from my previous website with craft was;

```
<div id="teamsimagebg" style="background-image:url({% if entry.teamImage1 | length %}{% for asset in entry.teamImage1 %}{{ asset.url }}{% endfor %}{% endif %});"></div>
```

Field handles were updated correctly and yet on the template page the image is not displayed.

After looking into this I found the following;

```
{% set asset = entry.teamImage1.first() %}

{% if asset %}
    {{ asset.url }}
{% endif %}
```

This had no effect either.

Comment: It might be to do with the way in which you're checking the asset variable. In your original version you have {% if entry.teamImage1 | length %} whereas in the new one you are just going with {% if asset %}. Have a look at this answer on checking for empty fields- http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/824/test-for-empty-field

Comment: Have you tried turning on devMode & {{ dump(asset) }} in your template. See if there's actually something in your asset variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an assets field with the fieldHandle `teamImage1` then the following should work.

```
{% if entry.teamImage1|length %}
    {% set asset = entry.teamImage1.first() %}
    {{ asset.url }}
{% endif %}
```