# currentUser: Impossible to invoke a method ("isInGroup") on a null variable

Tags: templating, users, user-groups, group, current-user

I couldn't find this anywhere else, I'm looking up if the `currentUser.isInGroup('verified')` and if not, display another link. Works fine when logged in but throws a Template and Runtime error when using the `{{logoutUrl}}` or viewing any page when not logged in.

I expected this would work the same as `currentUser` by itself, which throws no errors. But obviously there's something I'm missing. Should I be using something like [`craft.session`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.session) in combination with the `isInGroup`? Or some other method of detection?

[image]
[image]

**Update**

```
{% if currentUser.isInGroup('verified') is defined %}
```

Seems to get rid of the errors. So a couple of questions:

- Is this expected behaviour?

  - I'm yet to wrap my head around the `|length` `is defined` etc methods of checking, and when to use them. I'll have to [go over this post a few more times](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/824/test-for-empty-field/836#836)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's expected behavior.  `currentUser` will not exist if there is not a currently logged in user.

```
{% if currentUser.isInGroup('verified') is defined %}
```

That's one workaround for it.

Another would be:

```
{%if currentUser is defined and currentUser.isInGroup('verified') %}
```

which to me reads a little better even though it's more verbose.

Comment: Perfect, good to know. Using `currentUser` on it's own (without `is defined`) is perfectly fine though, right?

Comment: Yes, you can just do: `{%if currentUser and currentUser.isInGroup('verified') %}`

Comment: Nice one, thanks @khalwat ... that feels a little cleaner