# Using a Lightswitch to insert a class on a body's tag

Tags: templating, lightswitch

I'm trying to use a [Lightswitch](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/lightswitch-fields) field to insert a class on my body tag if the field is turned on.

What would be a good Twig template code to do this?

---

**Edit 1:**

Thanks for answering, guys. I still couldn't manage to do it, though. My lightswitch field handle is named whiteText. If I do this:

```twig
<body class='{% if whiteText('1') %}white{% endif %}'>
```

it'll just say:

> The function "whiteText" does not exist

(which I assume seems logical for you guys, but not for me).

And if I use `entry.whiteText` it'll say:

> Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure
>   named "whiteText".

I should also have some kind of "else" in the code, to output a clean -tag if the lightswitch is not switched on.

---

**Edit 2:**

I have now set up a global field. If I do `{{ globalfieldhandle.lightswitchfieldhandle }}` it outputs 0, even on the craft entry section I have it switched on (a single).

I need a way to make it say "1" if the lightswitch is turned on on the entry, and some help with the code to add a class on the body tag, and also the code for doing nothing if its not turned on.

Anyone?

The first answer to my question:

```
<body class='{% if lightswitch_field_handle %}class_name{% endif %}'>
```

seems like the right direction, but is it missing something?

Comment: Edit 2: A global field is available globally, in every template, you can't set it per section. If you replace `lightswitch_field_handle` with `entry.field_handle` it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi @Oyvind, and welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange site. I deleted your previous answer because it wasn't actually an answer to the question. (We have to keep things tidy around here so future visitors can learn from your hard work.) You can edit your original question as much as you want—it's a good idea if you have more troubleshooting the share that results in a more specific question.

Answer (score 6):

[Lightswitch fields](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/lightswitch-fields) save an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) to the database:

This integer can be checked just like a [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), with [Twigs if-tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html):

```twig
<body class='{% if lightswitch_field_handle %}class_name{% endif %}'>
```

> 1 = true  = on
>   0 = false = off

.

Twig has also a [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) which is similar to [php's ternary operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```twig
<body class="{{ lightswitch_field_handle ? 'class_name' }}">

<body class="{{ lightswitch_field_handle ? 'class_name' : 'alt_class_name' }}">
```

---

**Answer to Edit 1:**

Your example doesn't work because you aren't comparing: `if value == 1`, you are checking a function: `if function(param) == true`. Check out the [Twig if documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html) for more examples.

If `entry.whiteText` doesn't work, your section doesn't have such a field. If you added it to your main template, you should [check if the field is defined](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/356/177).

Comment: I'd also add the ternary style, Victor. `{{ lightswitch_field_handle ? 'class_name' }}`

Comment: Also `{{ lightswitch_field_handle ? 'class_name' : 'alt_class_name' }}`

Comment: Good point, thanks. Next time just edit it yourself ;)

Comment: I've had success with: {% if entry.myLightswitch == "0" %}Lightswitch is off{% endif %} and {% if entry.myLightswitch == "1" %}Lightswitch is on{% endif %}