# How to check if a DateTime attribute is set?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, records

I have a optional `dateFinished` attribute in my [Record](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/records):

```php
protected function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'dateFinished'  => AttributeType::DateTime,
        ...
    );
}
```

Some Records have it set to a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) other have it set to `null` (default).

To prevent Twig errors I tried using the [`is defined` test](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/356/177):

```twig
{{ log.dateFinished is defined ? log.dateFinished|date('m.d.y - H:m'|t) : '-'}}
```

But this doesn't work, I'm getting the typical "Scope error". After taking a look at the [`dump()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) it looks that even a `null` value is getting defined:

```php
  ["dateFinished"]=>
  object(Craft\DateTime)#2670 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-07-15 17:48:25"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(1)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(6) "+00:00"
  }

  ....

  ["dateFinished"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["column"]=>
    string(8) "datetime"
    ["type"]=>
    string(8) "datetime"
  }
```

I tried to solve this by "[Check(ing) if a variable is a date with Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14482336/3589841)":

```twig
{{ log.dateFinished is defined and log.dateFinished.timestamp is defined ? log.dateFinished|date('m.d.y - H:m'|t) : '-'}}
```

But this doesn't make a difference, I'm still getting the "Scope error". Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be returning a [record](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/records) instance to your templates directly. That can lead to all sorts of badness like templates being able to update the database themselves.

Have your plugin's [service](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/services) populate a [Mailer_LogModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/models) with just the attributes you want to expose to your template and return that.  Pretty sure after you do that, a simple:

```
{% if log.dateFinished %}
```

will work.

Comment: My bad, just checked again, and it still gives me a "Scope error". Also tried `log.dateFinished is defined and log.dateFinished is not iterable`.

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?  log.dateFinished is undefined?

Comment: `Craft\Mailer_LogRecord and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "dateFinished".`

Comment: OH!  Updating my answer. :)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Noob question: Is there a Yii-shortcut which can populate the model? (I need all attributes)

Comment: Mailer_LogModel::populateModel($record)

Comment: Note: For some reason when populating a Record, `model()` needs to be added: `Mailer_LogRecord::model()->populateRecord($log)`