# Conditional Parsing Issues

Tags: conditional

I'm not sure what's wrong with this original markup:

**Conditional One (doesn't work)**

```
{% if entry.metaTitle is defined %}
  {{ entry.metaTitle }}
{% elseif title is defined %}
  {{ title }}
{% else %}
  {{ siteName }}
{% endif %}
```

This works but seems a bit much for some simple checks:

**Conditional Two (does work)**

```
{% if entry.metaTitle is defined %}
  {{ entry.metaTitle }}
{% endif %}
{% if (title is defined) and (entry.metaTitle is empty) %}
  {{ title }}
{% endif %}
{% if (title is empty) and (entry.metaTitle is empty) %}
  {{ siteName }}
{% endif %}
```

As you can see I'm checking first if `metaTitle` is set, then `title` then finally fallback to `siteName`. Entering data for the first two return results, but not sure why if `metaTitle` and `title` are empty why `siteName` doesn't return in the first conditional

### #

**Update based on [Aaron's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8978/conditional-parsing-issues/8979#8979):**

Tried this too:

```
{% if (entry.metaTitle is defined) and (entry.metaTitle is empty)  %}
  {{ entry.metaTitle }}
{% elseif title is defined %}
  {{ title }}
{% else %}
  {{ siteName }}
{% endif %}
```

#

Also tried this, Aaron was missing a `(` in his answer :)

```
{% if (entry.metaTitle is defined) and (entry.metaTitle != '')  %}
  {{ entry.metaTitle }}
{% elseif title is defined %}
  {{ title }}
{% else %}
  {{ siteName }}
{% endif %}
```

But that doesn't work either with the same initial results.

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a situation where you might get away with just using [Twig's `default` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html):

```
{{ entry.metaTitle|default(title|default(siteName)) }}
```

It works even with undefined or empty strings, and methods that don't exist on objects that might not be defined themselves.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, the problem is in the first line of the conditional, `{% if entry.metaTitle is defined %}`.

If you are on an entry, `entry.metaTitle` will be defined as part of the entry model (even if it is empty), so your conditional returns true.

Give this a try:

```
{% if (entry.metaTitle is defined) and (entry.metaTitle != '')  %}
  {{ entry.metaTitle }}
{% elseif title is defined %}
  {{ title }}
{% else %}
  {{ siteName }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: no dice :( updating my question

Comment: Do you have any errors coming through in dev mode?

Comment: I gave it a try on one of my sites and my answer seems to work! Make sure you are doing `entry.metaTitle != ''` and not `entry.metaTitle is empty`, as that seems to make a difference.

Comment: nope :( updated my Q again :) nothing in dev mode re: errors.

Comment: Fixed my typo :) how are you setting `title`?

Comment: On my index page using `{% extends '_inc/_layout' %}{% set title = entry.heading %}`

Comment: What happens if you do a test when `title` has no value: `{{ title is defined ? 'defined' : 'not defined' }}`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is where the problem is...

```
...
{% elseif title is defined %}
    {{ title }}
...
```

I'd be willing to wager that **`title` is always defined**. Remember, [there is a difference between being defined vs. being empty](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/360/45).

Assuming your title is defined, but set to `null` or an empty string, you'll still be triggering this part of the if/else statement. But when you render the `{{ title }}` value, it will render as an empty string.

As a solution, try writing your second conditional like this:

```
...
{% elseif (title is defined) and (title is not empty) %}
    {{ title }}
...
```