# Correct code for a conditional field?

Tags: conditional

What's the correct way to create a conditional so that a field won't display if it's empty? Is it:

```
{% if entry.myentry | length %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if entry.myentry %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

I tried both and both seem to work, but I want to make sure they're both correct.

Comment: Not a dupe, but related: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/356/45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the field type. If it is an entry (or asset or user), then `entry.myentry` will be an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), which even if there are no elements will always be 'truthy'. In that case, you need `entry.myentry|length`.

Otherwise, depending on what you want to do about the field being `0` or `false` you may want one of:

- `entry.myentry` : true/false determined as in php. [twig if documentation explains this.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html)
- `entry.myentry is not empty` - false for `null`, `false`, empty array or empty string. ([empty](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/empty.html))
- `entry.myentry is not null` - false for `null`. ([null](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/null.html))
- `entry.myentry|length` - this will be `0` if entry.myentry is `false` or `null` and `1` if entry.myentry is `0`. ([length](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html))

I personally would `{{ dump(entry.myentry) }}` for one of your "empty" entries to get more clarity on which of these would be best.

Answer (score 8):

It depends. Technically to determine if a variable is not empty (keep in mind '0' or 'false' are not considered empty), you can use Twig's ['is not empty'](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/empty.html#empty):

```
{% if entry.myField is not empty %}...{% endif %}
```

But in most situations where '0' and/or 'false' are not expected values, then  anything that evaluates to '0', 'false' or 'null' will also work. So,

```
{% if entry.myField %}...{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if entry.myField|length %}...{% endif %}
```

If the field is not defined in the field layout however, these may also return an error. In which case you might want to use Twig's ['is defined'](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html#defined) first, before checking if the field is empty.

```
`{% if entry.myField is defined %}...{% endif %}`
```

In most cases, I just use `{% if entry.myField %}...{% endif %}`.

Comment: Not really related to the question but maybe this helps someone reading this great answer. You can get only those entries with non empty fields using a custom field parameter on the ElementCriteriaModel like so: `{% set entries = craft.entries.myField(':notempty:') %}`.