# Registration Form

Tags: form

I want to create a registration form in my website like Name, email and comments.

Once the end user filled the details, I would like to allow him to download a PDF.

Could any one please let me know how can I achieve it in Craft CMS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you us the [Craft Member Registration](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) form and have them register as actual Craft members.

Once they're members and logged in, you can display elements of a page using something like:

```
{% if currentUser %}
    Download this PDF...
{% endif %}
```

More info on the above, here: [How can I determine if a user is logged in, and who that user is?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/351/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-is-logged-in-and-who-that-user-is)

An obvious benefit to the above is that a member would only need to log in once and gain access to relevant content, instead of being asked to submit the information each time.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks Matt for quick turn around time. How can I use this registration form and where. I completely new to this CMS

Comment: @Prasanna I'd start by reading the Craft documentation (https://craftcms.com/docs) to get an overview of Craft specific concepts and for things like templating, which is what your'e looking for https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/