# Hiding specific items from public

Tags: lightswitch

So I want to hide certain items if a user is not logged into the website. I already have a custom lightswitch field on each of the items but I'm not sure on how to write the code for it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://craftcms.com/docs/lightswitch-fields and https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/352/5134:

```
{% if entry.lightswitchFieldHandle %}
    {% if currentUser %}
        Display entry that only logged users can see
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    Display entry that anyone can see
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How can I display the entry?